# Excel Formula - Count Value without repetition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm Having Problem Counting Unique Value with 3 column criteria.

[image: Here's The Excel Look]

[image: Here's What i Hope]

What i have tried is

```
 =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10;$E3;$C$2:$C$10;$F2)
```

How to detect the repeated ID without any criteria? 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a unique count or a distinct count. Excel does not have an out of the box formula for this.

Popular workarounds are: Create a pivot table from the data, using just the Type and Group field. Then do a pivot on the pivot table.

[image]

Or, with Excel 2016, you can add the table to the data model and build a pivot table with the new (to Excel 2016) aggregation "Distinct Count".

[image]

**Edit after comment:** To do a pivot of a pivot table, select a blank cell, click Insert > Pivot table and select the original pivot table as the source. For a detailed walk-through, take a look at Debra Dalgliesh's post https://www.contextures.com/pivottablecountunique.html

Comment: Hi teylyn, thanks for helping. can you tell me how to pivot on my pivot table ? and because i want to user VBA to create a macro, i can't use the distinct count summarized value.

Comment: I added more details to my answer.